# Create Require JS Module , Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I have a project in Backbone and Im using require js (I dont have to much experience  with require this is my first project with it , actually).

Now. On my home.js view I have a lot of functions like this

```
iScroll: function () {

                window.scrollers.myScroll = new iScroll(this.$('#products_container')[0], {
                    vScrollbar: true,
                    onScrollStart: function () {...........

swipeMobile: function () {
                $("#mobile_view").swipe({

                    swipe: function (event, direction, distance, duration, fingerCount) {
                        if (direction == "left") {....
```

I want to put all this functions in one separated module forexample "plugins" and to call function I need in my home.js view when I need it .

Im loading my templates on home view like this

```
define([
        'text!templates/about.html',
        'text!templates/home.html',
        'text!templates/product.html',
        'text!templates/contact.html',
        'collections/products'
    ],

    function (aboutTemplate, homeTemplate, productTemplate, contactTemplate, Products) {
```

Whats the easiest way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your collection of functions is an extension of a Backbone Model, Collection, or View, you can do the following:

```
define(['backbone'], function( Backbone ) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        customMethod: function() {
            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Then just require the path to the file and you can use it like so:

```
require(['path/to/custom/view'], function( CustomView ) {
    var customview = new CustomView();
    customview.customMethod(); // returns the Backbone view
});
```

Edit: If you have some code that *isn't* a Model, Collection or View, you can do this instead (assumes that this is a module with no dependencies):

```
define(function() {
    var MyCustomHelper = function() {
        this.someattribute = true;
    };

    MyCustomHelper.prototype.customMethod = function() {
        return this.someattribute;
    };

    return MyCustomHelper;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this ! Btw how it would look if i dont work with backbone , if just wan to make simple module to require it on pages I need it ?